# I am trying to open modal from the child component

Tags: react-native

I have tried many ways but non of these worked. I am trying from 5 days.
I used redux,props,then ref . Non of these helped. 
I need the modal to be visible when I call it from another class.

```
// this is the parent class
export default class Search1 extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.setModalVisible1 = this.setModalVisible1.bind(this);
   this.state = {
     modalVisible1: false,
   };
   this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
 }
   setModalVisible1(visible) {
       this.setState({ modalVisible1: visible });
       // this.setModalVisible2(visible);
   }
closeModal() {
   console.log("modalvi1 value is in closemodal ", this.state.modalVisible1);
   this.setState({ modalVisible1: false });
 }
   render() {
       return (
           {/* it renders the screen again when I call the */}
           <Modal
 closeModal={() => this.closeModal}
           animationType="slide"
           transparent={true}
           visible={this.state.modalVisible1}
           </Modal>
           <NavStack />
       );
   }
}
// this is the child class
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   render() {
<TouchableOpacity
               style={styles.firstStyle}
               onPress={() => {
                 this.props.closeModal();
                 );
               }}
             >
   return (

}
```

The modal should be visible when called from outer child class. It needs to be close when called from the parent class.

I tried using redux. that does not worked. Then I used props. Then I used the ref. None of these helped. Just get tired of this. Help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function to modal

```js
      closeModal() {
         this.setState({ modalVisible1: false });;
      }

                 <Modal
                  closeModal={this.closeModal}
                  animationType="slide"
                  transparent={true}
                  visible={this.state.modalVisible1} />
```

and run it on child component as this.props.closeModal()

Comment: Sir, Thank You so much for you response. But it gives an error which says t.props.closeModal is not a funciton.

Comment: Maybe binding is missing :)

Comment: I tried to bind it using several ways but still doesn't work. Your help will be 
highly appreciated.

Comment: if you show us full code it will be really easier to do it -> please edit your post.

Comment: I edited the code. Please see and let me know, whats wrong.

Comment: i cannot see modal component only home.screen

Comment: The Modal component is in the Search1 (parent) Class. I want to open it from the HomeScreen.js (child) Class.

Comment: Could you provide really full code with imports etc, because its really confusing.

Comment: Sir, i fixed the bindings but now it says D:\projects\expo7\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:76 Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.